# Type 'array | boolean' will not allow array methods because it might be boolean

Tags: arrays, typescript, boolean

private myVehicles: IVehicle[] | boolean;

Problem:
When I receive a list of vehicles from database, I want to set them to myVehicles, or push them individually into myVehicles array.  TS errors because myVehicles MIGHT be a boolean. "push" is not a property of 'boolean'  Yes I know... but it is a method for array...

I can probably do away with | boolean and rework the logic but I see this quite frequently and seems there must be a way around it.

Comment: why would you type it as boolean in the first place. ?

Comment: `if (typeof myVehicles === 'boolean') { ... } else { ... }`?

Comment: `private myVehicles: IVehicle[] | false;` may be better if it is `false` or an array, and that is easier to narrow the type. If you use type unions, you need to understand how to narrow to the specific type to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An union type lets you use only the common characteristics between the two terms. The only common characteristic between a `Boolean` and an `Array` is `Object.prototype.valueOf`. In order to use this variable properly just leverage [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) and handle the two cases separately:

```
interface IVehicle { }

declare const myVehicles: IVehicle[] | boolean;

if (typeof myVehicles === 'boolean') {
  // Here you can handle the boolean case
} else {
  // Here you can handle the IVehicle[] case
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDUIAtgIDYoDeyAvgFBkAmE+cUKCA9iAM5jIC2AnpjvhCwBcaXrgIBtALrIAPsgBGjRgTggA3BWAxkACjBcADhEbbuo-i2QBeG8gDki5RFV2AlMkJlkyAPQ-kABLQKFyMAK7ICKrIWKqUBMhgWCiOKiCRcCwQZCTIEHhZHl6+-kH0yKERUemxIPEoSSgY2GIQUhlZOUA)

Comment: // Here you can handle the IVehicle stuff...

If I try myVehicles.push(IVehicleArray) TypeScript will still error saying it might be boolean. I think I will just have to use empty array when there is no data rather than false or null.

Comment: Using an empty array when there is no data would be a wise decision. However, I see no reason why my code doesn't work for you. Are you running an old TypeScript version? Does it work in the playground? Is `myVehicles` an actual property of another object?

Comment: It also works within a class: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDUIAtgIDYoDeyAvgFBn5wDO1yAKhNWMoWch8gA5TABucSMgC2AT0w58TAFxoJuAgG0AusgA+yAEYB7bQTggA3BU7IE2kMygBXBGG1QAFADpXcKAHNqsg6JUBKVnZTTjAcamcxeSk6AF5kdy9FAAZlY1NyYI5IZkdAthDOYBhkRzBRLghtErDgCKjsBSZkWNbkAHIdPQgDdvysws4AeiHkAAloFFFtazMDZCwDABMCZDCULv0QOeoIAYzkCDxdoMGQkfHJ5GnZhHnFkBWUdblGqRUdvf3B2vrxN4IES41moWEchBI-m+HHIGTImSAA